# HTML input and submitting

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to input some values and put it below after submitted, but every time the browser just refresh itself and add "?a=&b=" to the original url. The added content will then disappear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function calculate(){
            var aNode = document.getElementById('a');
            var bNode = document.getElementById('b');
            var a = parseFloat(aNode.value);
            var b = parseFloat(bNode.value);
            var result = a / Math.pow(b,2);
            result = result.toFixed(2);
            var commentText = document.createTextNode(result);
            var node = document.getElementById("comments")
            node.appendChild(commentText);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name = "form" action = "index.html" onSubmit = "calculate()">
    num1 <input id="a" type="text" name="a"><br>
    num2 <input id="b" type="text" name="b"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
    </form>
    <p id="comments"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do know that the "submit" feature is intended to be used to send data to the Web Server, don't you?  And that, sometimes, is associated with a reload of the page from the Web Server?

Comment: you want to retain the url parameters even after refresh ?

Comment: I tried prevent this refresh and add the result to that p tag

Comment: I worked it out myself, Changed submit into onclick lol

Comment: @sdfasdfw Uhm, I guess you can click anywhere on your form to start the process now. Is that really what you want? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default **method** of a form is **get**. This will redirect your browser to the url specified in **action** and add the form input values to the url. If you just want to calculate something I recommend @Stu s answer.

If you want to calculate something and submit the form after some validation or encode values with md5 or whatever you could go with that:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="targetFile.php" onSubmit="calculate()">
```

This would post your values to the url specified in action and you could get the values on targetFile.php using phps $_GET["inputname"]. If for some reson you want to abord submitting due to invalid input you have to return false in your calculate(). That would abord the process.

This is maybe too much info but still nice to know I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
<form name = "form" action = "index.html" onSubmit = "calculate(); return false;">
```

N.B. : the use of on*event* (onclick, onsubmit, onblur, etc.) inside HTML is bad practice...

Comment: +1 for mentioning to write as less css or js as possible in html

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be simpler just to remove the form and call `Calculate()` onClick of a button?

```
<body>
    num1 <input id="a" type="text" name="a"><br>
    num2 <input id="b" type="text" name="b"><br>
    <button type="button" onClick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <p id="comments"></p>
</body>
```